# Preposizioni davanti a nomi di prodotti come WhatsApp, Facebook, Instagram

Tags: grammar, prepositions, proper-nouns

Quale preposizione si deve mettere davanti alle parole Facebook, WhatsApp, Instagram, ... ?

È corretto dire:
Guardare su Facebook? Scrivere su WhatsApp? Postare in Instagram?

Si può dire:
Hai in questo numero WhatsApp? - la preposizione 'in' mi pare strana; si può dire avere su questo numero?

Comment: Mi sembra che la tua domanda abbia più a che fare con i nomi di prodotti che col fatto che questi nomi derivino dall'inglese. Io comunque dico *Hai whatsapp su questo numero?*

Comment: Penso che @DenisNardin abbia ragione. Forse si dovrebbe modificare il titolo della domanda.

Comment: Delle soluzioni potrebbero essere _Usi WhatsApp con questo numero?_ oppure _Hai WhatsApp in questo telefono?_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La risposta alla tua domanda dipende dal senso della frase, quindi la preposizione può variare a seconda di quello che intendi dire.

È corretto dire: “Ti mando un messaggio **su** WhatsApp”, ma anche: “Ti mando un messaggio **per** WhatsApp”.

Considera che spesso in italiano alcune parole sono **sottintese**, quindi:

> “Ti mando un messaggio **su** WhatsApp” = **sull’applicazione** WhatsApp;
>
> “Ti mando un messaggio **per** WhatsApp” = **per mezzo dell’applicazione** WhatsApp;

Sebbene non sia una preposizione, potresti anche scrivere:

> “Ti mando un messaggio **via** WhatsApp”.

Postare **su** Facebook, **su** Instagram = postare **sul sito** Facebook, **sul sito** (o sull'applicazione) Instagram, ecc.

Se pensi alla parola che potrebbe essere sottintesa nella frase, è più facile trovare la preposizione giusta.

Spero che questo possa esserti di aiuto.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!